Set multiple mutations in graphql query
I have the following mutation which works:
   `#graphql
  mutation discountAutomaticAppCreate($automaticAppDiscount: DiscountAutomaticAppInput!) {
    discountAutomaticAppCreate(automaticAppDiscount: $automaticAppDiscount) {
      userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
      automaticAppDiscount {
        discountId
        title
        startsAt
        endsAt
        status
        appDiscountType {
          appKey
          functionId
        }
        combinesWith {
          orderDiscounts
          productDiscounts
          shippingDiscounts
        }
      }
    }
  }`,
  {
    variables: {
      "automaticAppDiscount": {
        "title": title,
        "functionId": "sdfgsdfg4345-493e-bb17-b08837ddbe3d",
        "startsAt": "2024-02-02T17:09:21Z",
        "metafields": [
          {
            "namespace": title,
            "key": "tags",
            "type": "json",
            "value": "{\"value\":\"42\"}"
           // "value": "{\"discounts\":[{\"value\":{\"fixedAmount\":{\"amount\":5}},\"targets\":\n                      [{\"orderSubtotal\":{\"excludedVariantIds\":[]}}]}],\"discountApplicationStrategy\":\"FIRST\"}"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  }

However I need to change this to be a mutation which runs two mutations at once.
Here is my attempt but I get an error with the variable $automaticAppDiscount:
         `#graphql
      mutation {
      discountAutomaticAppCreate: discountAutomaticAppCreate($automaticAppDiscount: DiscountAutomaticAppInput!) {
        discountAutomaticAppCreate(automaticAppDiscount: $automaticAppDiscount) {
          userErrors {
            field
            message
          }
          automaticAppDiscount {
            discountId
            title
            startsAt
            endsAt
            status
            appDiscountType {
              appKey
              functionId
            }
            combinesWith {
              orderDiscounts
              productDiscounts
              shippingDiscounts
            }
          }
        }
      }
    addPost: addPost {
    id
    title
    content
  }
      }`,
      {
        variables: {
          "automaticAppDiscount": {
            "title": title,
            "functionId": "142a51d8-f06c-493e-bb17-b08837ddbe3d",
            "startsAt": "2024-02-02T17:09:21Z",
            "metafields": [
              {
                "namespace": title,
                "key": "tags",
                "type": "json",
                "value": "{\"value\":\"42\"}"
               // "value": "{\"discounts\":[{\"value\":{\"fixedAmount\":{\"amount\":5}},\"targets\":\n                      [{\"orderSubtotal\":{\"excludedVariantIds\":[]}}]}],\"discountApplicationStrategy\":\"FIRST\"}"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
      }

